# How can I put ad banners in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to return banners in a list view after every n rows

I got this, it works but when I scroll down the list gets distorted and rows start to overlap. the ad banner starts to float up the list.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        RestHolder holder = null;
        boolean showAd = proVersion == false
                && (position == 3 || (position % 6 == 0 && position != 0 && position != 6));
        if (showAd) {
            if (row instanceof Banner) {
                return row;
            } else {
                            //declared startAppBanner in the constructor
                return startAppBanner;
            }
        }
        if (row == null || row instanceof Banner) {
            System.err.println("### notusing row");
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((SherlockActivity) context)
                    .getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(viewResourceId, parent, false);
           ....
```

Comment: you have to create a adapter capable of using different views, see androids BaseAdapter and have a look at this tutorial: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296